Is it true that so many priests left the priesthood after Vatican II?
I once heard that so many priests, monks and nuns left their vocations and returned to lay state immediately after Vatican council II ended. Is this true?
I also heard that so many convents and monasteries shutdown. I know now that churches across Europe continue to shutdown and Christianity dwindle. But is there any official trustworthy statistics or records for all this? Is there a good reference that talks about these issues?
Update 1:
I found the following SSPX research paper Fruits of Vatican II:

But I need more guidance in evaluating it (how valuable it is and what other research exists in this are, especially books treating this matter).
Update 2:
Another resource I found is a blog article by the same title by Patrick Hawkins, a contributor to One Peter 5 (a website for restoring Catholic Tradition).
But again, I am looking for a trustworthy interpretation of this data in the form of a book.
Update 3:
Another is a book list on Second Vatican Council by Dr. Peter and Julian Kwasniewski.

Yes, it is true. Many were disappointed by the lack of reform, many others were disappointed by the reform going to far. I can tell you from the people I spoke to, and from memory, but I don't have the sources you are looking for.

I hope you don't mind me annotating the resources you linked.  I notice that all of them are from Catholics who advocated Traditional Latin Mass, so it's not surprising they blame Vatican II for introducing Novus Ordo among other "dilutions" of traditional teachings.  But I think other reasons might be more contributory for priests leaving the priesthood and for the current shortage of vocations to replenish the priests who are retiring, at least in the West.

One hint I came across is a Britannica article The church since Vatican II that says: "The discontent with life and ministry led to a large number of departures from the priesthood, most dramatically following Paul VI’s encyclical Sacerdotalis caelibatus (June 24, 1967; “Priestly Celibacy”), which confirmed the necessity of celibacy."

@GratefulDisciple Re 1st comment: No problem at all. If you have any convincing explanations from the other side I would love to hear them. It seems to me that the post vatican ii church does not seem interested in this topic, as when I was seaching online I wasn't limiting myself specifically to TLM views.. But they are all I found..

I've been looking for some details and I'm disappointed with the sources I've got but... here is what I found.


More obviously apparent was the loss of priests. In the 10 years after the council 100,000 men left the priesthood worldwide. -TheGuardian


This week [October 2012], Cardinal Schoenborn of Vienna, one of the most intelligent conservatives in the modern church, announced plans to reduce his diocese from 660 parishes to 150. There just aren't the priests or people to service any more.  -TheGuardian, (Ibid)


Many more catholic sources, are neglectfully absent for the numbers. They however often refer to how the majority of Catholics who had experienced the 1950s High Mass did not like the new version.

All sources here are found in this link from the Church Times (in the UK)

Surveying the evidence of the past half-century, Dr Stephen Bullivant, Professor of Theology and the Sociology of Religion at St Mary’s University, Twickenham, concludes that the Council was a conspicuous failure. The sociologist Anthony Spencer has calculated that about 30,000 Catholics “dropped out” in the course of 1959, but, by the late 1960s, this had risen to 235,000 per year.


In Britain, nearly half of all born-and-raised Roman Catholics no longer consider themselves to be Catholic. Of all affiliates, fewer than one in three attend church each week (another third never go to church). Leavers from Roman Catholicism outnumber converts by ten to one. The Bishops’ Conference of England and Wales estimates that there are four million lapsed RCs in England and Wales.


Causality is, he notes, “notoriously difficult to prove”. -Dr Bullivant

Lapsation was an issue during this period already within the catholic community, so while some of it might be because of the Vatican 2... some of it might have been for other reasons.
The article mentions a book full of the statistics you are asking for called "Mass Exodus", I've not found the contents of the book to be able to provide the information you are asking about in specific high quality detail, and I've not seen any other statistical data.

So the answer appears to be "Yes, many catholics and priests broke away"

Thank you for you valuable response. I have updated the question with more information.

Is it true that so many priests left the priesthood after Vatican II?
No one doubts that many priests have left the priesthood since the end of the Second Vatican Council. However the figures and reasons for this are often convoluted.
For example The Guardian states that some 100,000 priests have left the priesthood in the first 10 years following Vatican II. However this seems to somewhat high.

The media talk about priests very often, but unfortunately they do so above all in order to divulge instances of scandal or to condemn the Church's attitudes, judged as being too harsh toward them. There is a good deal less talk about the personal care that the Church constantly exercises toward priests. [...]
What is the situation today of those who, after having abandoned the priesthood – something that usually happens amid great suffering – ask to be readmitted to the priestly ministry? Who are they, and how many? Because the figures that are circulated in this arena are sometimes farfetched, we would like to present accurate information about both the abandonment of the priestly ministry, and about the rather less well-known phenomenon of the readmittance to it of those who had left it behind. This is, in fact, in our view, an area that demonstrates in ways that are more easily understood today the care of persons on the part of the Church, or more precisely the "maternity" of the Church, something that is rarely emphasized.
There are no exact figures on the numbers of priests who, having left the ministry, are now married. On the basis of indications sent to the Vatican from the dioceses, from 1964 to 2004, 69,063 priests left the ministry. From 1970 to 2004, 11,213 priests have returned to the ministry. This means that there cannot be more than 57,000 married priests. Probably there are many fewer, because over forty years a number of them have died. So the figures cited by the press and by the associations of married priests, speaking of 80,000-100,000 ex-priests, are unfounded. - Priests Who "Desert," Priests Who "Come Back"

The article Vatican Finds Big Increase in Priests Who Quit from the NY Times shows much lower numbers than were generally believed!
To be honest the shortage of priests, is in part due to the lack of vocations to the priesthood as well as because of certain priests abandoning their priesthood.
